# Add Animation to View Change

Tags: ios, xcode, animation

So after a lot of research if finally found the code that allows me to change to another view without giving me any errors:

```
UIViewController * vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"gameOverPage"];
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setRootViewController:vc];
```

The only problem with this code is that there is no animation. I want to somehow add the cross dissolve animation to this if possible.

Another major problem is that it shows the view two times (some times three). So it goes to the second view and then less than a second later, it shows the page again. I know this because iAd is reloaded and when I press a button that goes to another page, it is interrupted by the second page coming up again.

Answer (score 0):

To change the view to another (navigating) you don't need to `setRootViewController:` set it as root view controller always.

you can use a `UINavigationController` and set a `UIViewController` as root, then to change view use `pushViewController:` method of navigation controller, like

```
//Pre condition - already a viewController is root view controller of navigation controller.
UIViewController * vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"gameOverPage"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animted:YES];
```

Another way is,

```
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Read more [presentViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_68), [UINavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: `[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animted:YES];` doesn't do anything and `[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];` spams me with this error: `Warning: Attempt to present <GameOver: 0xbd648a0> on <Game: 0xbd5f4a0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

Comment: From where you calling `presentViewController:vc`? from `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: No. I'm calling it when the player has lost the game. By the way, I've seen a lot of posts where people use presentViewController in viewDidLoad. Why load a new view when your current view just loaded? I can't make out a good reason for this.

Comment: The point is that, view controller's view will not be in the window's view hierarchy at the point that it has been loaded (when the viewDidLoad message is sent).

Comment: So how do I fix this issue that I have now?